# Fridge door left open

Tags: food-safety

I know its probably a silly question but i left the fridge door cracked slightly open last night for around 3 and a half to 4 hours and was wondering if the freezer would have been affected in anyway?. I worry needlessly about everything and overthink compulsively so cant let this go. I imagine all the fridge items would be ok also as i said it was only cracked about 1 inch open for just about less than 4 hours..

Comment: Fridge or freezer?

Comment: it was the fridge door that i left open.. but was just wondering if the then in turn would the freezer be affected in anyway.. i know it sounds silly but i overthink everything...

Comment: Please add additional information: was there excessive ice on the inside back, was there melt water?

Answer (score 2):

If the door was only open a small amount, but the refrigerator was still running, it is likely things remained cold enough. However, there is no way for me to know for sure. Temperature is the key.  If the interior remained below 40 degrees F, your food is fine.  If it crept up into the danger zone for more than 2 hours, then you should be concerned.  In terms of the freezer, unless your food thawed, you are probably alright.